# Debugging PowerShell Azure Durable Functions in VSCode

Tags: powershell, vscode-debugger, azure-durable-functions

While developing my first durable function using PowerShell in VSCode, I am experiencing a troubled debugging experience. Often times the debugger is not attached correctly to my orchestration function so my breakpoints do not hit. Other times they do work correctly.

I realize that POSH + Durable functions will do stuff like creating separate runspaces or something and a remote debugging bridge that is hidden from your experience. What are your experiences with POSH + Durable Functions in VSCode? Does this actually work?

Cheers, Wouter

Answer (score 0):

***I have created Powershell Durable Azure functions in VScode to check if debugging works:***

- Created Durable function and could execute successfully:

[image]

To debug your function, write `wait-debugger` where you want to start debugging.

- Go to Run and Debug in the left pane of vscode, Enable `Run and Debug`:

[image]

Choose *Add Configuration* from the drop down and select `Attach to powershell functions`.

[image]

[image]

When clicking on the function URL, it is hitting the debugger point and waiting for further action:

[image]

[image]

**References:**

[Debug PowerShell Azure Functions locally | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-debug-powershell-local)